# Secure key storage in Android Application

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I know this isn't exactly a programming topic, but maybe someone has experience with this topic.

I need to store three 128-bit keys for authentication in my Android application.
How to do it the safest way so that a simple decompilation of the application will not allow to read these codes ?  Generally, what to do to make these keys secure

I use Delphi 11.

Comment: Suggest starting with Android documentation for the Android keystore system: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore then check various Android guides like https://guides.codepath.com/android/Storing-Secret-Keys-in-Android then finally implement your chosen method in Delphi.

Comment: @Brian Isn't it safer to keep the keys on the server ? How then to secure the entire process of sending such a key from the server to the application?

Answer (score 1):

You want to distribute some fixed keys in your executable. My guess is that you want only your application to be able to connect to an API, or a device. Then you use symmetric encryption from these keys.

From what [this official guide says about storing secrets in Android](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Storing-Secret-Keys-in-Android), the best way is to obfuscate the key within native code. Luckily enough, your Delphi application is a native application, so more difficult to disassemble than an Android/JVM application.

So I would just use SHA2/SHA3 derivation from several constants (which may be a mix of text and binary) in the source code - perhaps from a `.inc` file if you want to keep it secret and not part of the source code repository. You may hash the binary content of a small bounded resource, e.g. a picture. This obfuscation process could be some pure pascal code, which would be difficult to hack for the average hacker. Just don't store the keys as plain constant somewhere in your code/executable: derivate the key from some existing material - this is where SHA2/SHA3 could be good enough, e.g. with a PBKDF2 algorithm and a high number of rounds.

Don't make something too complex: if your attacker is good enough to disassemble some pascal compiled ARM, he/she is likely to defeat anything you may define in-house.

But I would always say that such fixed keys will never be safe. If I could, I would use asymmetric keys, with key derivation from two public/private key pairs. I would put the private key in a safe place (e.g. a server accessible via an API), then call once this API when the user registers the app. It would make e.g. a ECDH challenge with the private key stored in the other server API, or the device. Then I would perhaps store this secret in a safe place, [using e.g. the Android KeyStore API](https://medium.com/@ericfu/securely-storing-secrets-in-an-android-application-501f030ae5a3).

Anyway, what I would always do is provide a way to revoke the keys. An application update may be enough in such case.

And if you can, let your code be audited by someone - even not familiar with Delphi - which knows about security and cryptography.